# Minimum number of observations per group in a prediction model

Tags: prediction, sample-size, statistical-power

I ran a univariate logistic regression analysis on some risk factors for a dichotomous outcome. One of the variables is highly significant, but only has 5 outcomes in one of the groups. The confidence interval ends up being very wide when I run a multivariable regression. Is it appropriate to include it, or should I remove it from the multivariable model?

Comment: *"only has 5 outcomes in one of the groups."* which groups?

Comment: *"The confidence interval ends up being very wide when I run a multivariable regression"* is this where you obtained the high significance? If not, what model did you do that got the high significance?

Comment: Might be better to explain with more details on the variables: outcome is death (0/1). The predictor is disease x (0/1). So only 5 patients with disease x were alive, but over 20 were dead. Univariately we have a highly significant association, so I put it in the multivariable model. In the multivariable model, we still have high significance but the CI for the OR is really wide.

Comment: So disease $x$ is an extremely good predictor of mortality? How many patients did you have alive in total? How was the information collected (regarding independence, was it more or less likely to find a combination death-disease due to the sampling)? What would have been the expected number of alive patients in the desease x group?

Comment: Over 200 patients alive and only 41 dead. Information was collected independently (no sampling issues).

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression has a known issue with overadjustment. Estimates of the odds ratio become biased in smaller samples: the OR tends toward it's square. So an OR of 2 tends to 4 as the statistical power to detect that odds ratio diminishes. The CI widens with this tendency as well so that the interval estimates are anticonservative for replications of the design. [See, also, a relevant answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331871/maximum-number-of-categorical-predictors-in-multinomial-polytomous-logistic-re/331896#331896).

The amount of information you can glean from this analysis is somewhat limited and disappointing:

- This feature probably has prognostic value
- The analysis is not adequately powered to give precise estimates.
- The risk prediction model will tend to be miscalibrated by underestimating risk in people not afflicted with this exposure.
- The risk model which omits this factor will estimate a reduced model precisely, but has the subsequent omitted variable bias which will have unanticipated and limited generalizabiity.

The efficient solution is re-estimate sample size, and possibly use targetted, two-phase sampling to be able to reliably estimate the impact of this exposure in the context of a multivariate model.